# Differences in Security (HW-Encryption) of iPhone 3GS and iPhone4/4S

Tags: iphone, hardware, data-protection

I have an iPhone 4S and an iPhone 3GS here for research purposes. In the following weeks I want to perform some security tests especially based on the hardware encryption and Apple's Data Protection API. This also includes to find some potential attack scenarios. So I guess I have to jailbreak one of the devices for it.

So the question is: Are there any differences in case of hardware-encryption, security mechanism, data protection and so on on the iPhone 4S compared to the iPhone 3GS. Because I would prefer to jailbreak the 3GS but it must also be representive for the newest generation of devices (the iPhone 4S).

I am not sure if stack overflow is the right place to ask this but I think it is a question regarding the hardware specific implementation of the security mechanism and the security software in the OS. So I think this would be too much detailed for apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Apple does not give any insight into the hardware encryption capabilities of the CPU in either phone, nevermind a comparison.  They do not publish security information, only that they have passed testing performed by certain agencies who are under NDA not to reveal any details other than the security level to which the devices are certified. I would be very interested to learn of your results, but I don't believe there's much good information publicly available about it at the moment.

Comment: Basically, they provide information about how it works: http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf But you are right, I also haven't found any information about the differences on their devices. I'm sure there must be some info. At least, I have found several information about the HW Encryption on their newest devices from a Blackhat conference. (Didn't find the link actually)